# PHP formatting date, without using date functions

Tags: php

I am getting date in following format, which is a string:

```
31_Dec_2010
```

Now, I need to convert it to following 2 format

```
2010-12-31 //(for use in mysql query)
```

and

```
31 Dec, 2010 //(for displaying purpose)
```

I **cannot use Date-Time Functions** because I am running code on PHP 4.8

Please suggest me some way, other then "explode" function

Comment: The documentation says that `date` is available in PHP 4...

Comment: @Felix Kling : http://fr2.php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php

Comment: it's very simple string operation. You desperately need to learn basic string manipulations.

Comment: PHP 4 has `strftime`, which solves half of your problem. Why not `explode`? Could you qualify your (otherwise arbitrary) requirements? Upgrade...? PHP 4 hasn't been in development for over 2 years now, and PHP 5 has been out for at least half a decade...

Comment: @ClemDesm: Ah ok, I see. He is referring to the *`DateTime` class*. Thanks.

Comment: The `DateTime` class is not available in PHP4, but the basic date handling functions (`date`, `mktime`, `strtotime` et al.) are.

Comment: Are you sure that the version is really __4.8__?

Comment: your version of php is dangerously out of date upgrade or get hacked.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do like this:

```
echo date('Y-m-d', strtotime(str_replace('_', '-', '31_Dec_2010')));
```

**Output:**

```
2010-12-31
```

---

> I cannot use Date-Time Functions
>   because I am running code on PHP 4.8

These functions are available in the version of PHP you are using :)

Comment: .. and echo date('d M, Y', strtotime(str_replace('_', '-', '31_Dec_2010'))); for the "31 Dec, 2010"

Comment: And `date('d M, Y', strtotime(str_replace('_', '-', '31_Dec_2010')));` ?

Answer (score 0):

According to the manual PHP's date functions have been available since version 4. Assuming you cant update (for whatever reason), you still should be able to use them.

You should reconsider using explode/split, you can safely split on _ to get each part of the date. The only tedious part of that is to convert the month to the numeric value, MySQL might have some handy syntax for that too.